# How can I (at compile time) determine if a typename is a function pointer typename?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Consider the following wrapper around Win32's Runtime Dynamic Linking mechanism:

```
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Exception.hpp"

namespace WindowsApi
{
    class RuntimeDynamicLinker : boost::noncopyable
    {
        HMODULE hMod_;
    public:
        RuntimeDynamicLinker(const wchar_t * moduleName)
        {
            hMod_ = LoadLibraryW(moduleName);
            if (hMod_ == 0)
            {
                Exception::Throw(GetLastError());
            }
        }
        template <typename T>
        T GetFunction(const char* functionName)
        {
            FARPROC result = GetProcAddress(hMod_, functionName);
            if (result == 0)
            {
                Exception::Throw(GetLastError());
            }
            return reinterpret_cast<T>(result);
        }
        ~RuntimeDynamicLinker()
        {
            FreeLibrary(hMod_);
        }
    };
}
```

And an example client:

```
typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI * NtQueryInformationProcess_t)(
    IN HANDLE,
    IN PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS,
    OUT PVOID,
    IN ULONG,
    OUT PULONG);
RuntimeDynamicLinker ntdll(L"ntdll.dll");
NtQueryInformationProcess_t NtQueryInformationProcess = 
    ntdll.GetFunction<NtQueryInformationProcess_t>("NtQueryInformationProcess");
```

Basically, I'd like to add an error message if anyone tries to use `GetFunction` where `T` is anything other than a function pointer type (because the `reinterpret_cast` I'm forced to use here could otherwise hide user errors).

Digging through boost type traits, I did find that there's an existing [`is_function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_function.html) template. However, `is_function` accepts references to functions, which would be a user error in my case (function *pointers* only).

How can I modify `RuntimeDynamicLinker::GetFunction<T>()` to produce a reasonably understandable compiler error message if `T` is not a function pointer type?

(Side note: I've never done any kind of TMP, so don't be afraid to go over things that are "basic" to regular users of TMP)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `is_pointer<T>::value && is_function<remove_pointer<T>::type>::value` in a `static_assert`/`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`.

Comment: +1 because this seems to do exactly what I need. (though waiting to see if there are other answers first)

Comment: +1 because [according to the Boost documentation this is how you detect if a type is a function pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_function.html).

Comment: @Stephane Rolland: These traits are available now in recent C++03 compilers via the Boost.TypeTraits library. (However, `static_assert` is a C++0x feature. Use `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` for that.)

Comment: @In silico: 1. I am a complete idiot -- I linked to that in my question! 2. Doesn't the doc need a `typename` in there?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Hmm... perhaps a documentation bug? :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use a Trait class.

```
template <typename T>
class IsFunctionPointer
{
public:
    bool isFunctionPointer(){return false;};
}

typedef void (*MyFunctionPointer)();

template <>
class IsFunctionPointer<MyFunctionPointer>
{
public:
    bool isFunctionPointer(){return true;};
}
```

this is the basic idea of a [Trait class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traits_class).

EDIT: i will ad a few articles link for introducing traits. personnally It took some time for me before grasping them :-)

http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442

Comment: +1 because this would work, but it doesn't work in my specific case because then I'd have to define every possible function pointer type in advance, which is unreasonable for something as large as win32.

Comment: Though I do suppose you could make isFunctionPointer use the enum hack in order to satisfy my "At compile time" requirement.

Comment: Ok, all possible functions... hmm... what do you mean by the enum hack ?

Comment: http://codepad.org/e51heAWV or http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%2B%2B+enum+hack

Comment: Great ! thanx ! it's better than the call of to a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `boost::enable_if` like so:

```
template <typename T>
T GetFunction(const char* functionName, 
   typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_pointer<T>::value 
      && boost::is_function<typename boost::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value>::type* = 0)
{
   ....
}
```

This will only allow a template parameter that is a pointer and also a function.  Anything else will not bind to the function at compile time.

So that:

```
GetFunction<int(*)()>("foo"); // compiles properly
GetFunction<int()>("foo"); // fails to compile
```

Comment: +1 because this one has the `typename` you need for `remove_pointer`.

Comment: +1 because [according to the Boost documentation this is how you detect if a type is a function pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_function.html).