# Detect if a given type is a function type in C++03

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, c++03

Is there any way to detect at compile-time whether a given type is a function type in C++03 when I don't know the function's signature? If so, how?

(I only need this for free functions, not member functions.)

Comment: There's `boost::is_function` but without `decltype` it'll be annoying to use.

Comment: A SFINAE test with `test(void *)` and `test(...)`, since function pointers are not convertible to void pointers?

Comment: @Rapptz: Whoops, I just realized this is a dupe... http://stackoverflow.com/q/4416144/541686 (Edit: never mind, that's not C++03)

Comment: @KerrekSB: But what about class types?

Comment: Class types are object types. Filter out reference types and void, you can do that easily with specializations.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sorry I shouldn't have brought up reference types. But I don't get how I'm supposed to filter out normal types. What if someone passes `int` for example?

Comment: My point is this: For a given `T`, check if `T *` is convertible to `void *`. If not, then it is a function type.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Ohhhh I misunderstood! 1 sec, lemme try that, thanks.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Ugh, doesn't quite work on VC++...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Found a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution myself, thanks to Kerrek SB's initial hint:

```
template<class T> struct is_function
{
private:
    static T &declval;
    static char (&test(T *))[2];
    template<class U>
    static char (&test(U const &))[1];
public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(test(declval)) > 1;
};

template<> struct is_function<void> { static bool const value = false; };
template<class T> struct is_function<T const> : is_function<T> { };
template<class T> struct is_function<T volatile> : is_function<T> { };
template<class T> struct is_function<T const volatile> : is_function<T> { };
template<class T> struct is_function<T &> { static bool const value = false; };
```

Turns out member function pointers are easy too:

```
template<class> struct is_member_function_pointer { static bool const value = false; };
template<class T> struct is_member_function_pointer<T const> : is_member_function_pointer<T> { };
template<class T> struct is_member_function_pointer<T volatile> : is_member_function_pointer<T> { };
template<class T> struct is_member_function_pointer<T const volatile> : is_member_function_pointer<T> { };
template<class T, class U> struct is_member_function_pointer<T U::*> : is_function<T> { };
```

Comment: Just add specializations: `template<class T> struct is_function<T&> { static bool const value = false; }; template<> struct is_function<void> { static bool const value = false; };`

Comment: @aschepler: Yeah, that.

Comment: Heh, I overlooked that aschepler's comment already pointed out the same thing I attempted to point out in my previous now-deleted comment. It could be worth editing that into your answer. (+1 nonetheless)